# How to return int from select option value in plain html in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a plain html form which contains a select option, the select option value should return an int to be stored in the database.

I have tried converting the value to int in the view but it still doesnt work.

This is the ScrummyGoals Model

```py
class ScrummyGoals(models.Model):
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(ScrummyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #goal_status = models.ForeignKey(GoalStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #task_target = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    target_name = models.ForeignKey(GoalStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1, related_name="scrummygoals")



    def __str__(self):
        return self.task
```

This is the model from which I am populating the select options.

```py
class GoalStatus(models.Model):
    target = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=target, default="Week")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.target
```

This is the html form

```html
<form action="" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="task">Task</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task" name="task">
  </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="task">Goal</label>
         <select name="goal" class="form-control">
             {% for goal in goal %}
             <option value='{{goal.id | to_int }}'>{{goal.target}}</option>
             {% endfor %}
         </select>

  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create task</button>
</form>
```

This is the view which I am getting the post request and saving to the database.

```py
def user_add_task(request):
    goal = GoalStatus.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('task') and request.POST.get('goal'):
            task = ScrummyGoals()
            task.target_name = int(request.POST.get('goal'))
            task.user_name = request.user.scrummyuser.id
            task.task = request.POST.get('task')
            task.save()
            return redirect('myapp:home')
    return render(request, 'myapp/user_add_task.html', {'goal':goal})
```

I expect the value of the select option to be an int e.g 1 not a string e.g "1".
So I get this error: 
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:

Cannot assign "1": "ScrummyGoals.target_name" must be a "GoalStatus" instance.

Comment: you should provide the ScrummyGoals model. you're trying to assign wrong type of data to ```target_name```, I suppose.

Comment: You didn't read the error message. Django does not want an int there.

Comment: I really do not understand

Comment: Please fix your naming: I guess I'm not alone here confused. `GoalStatus`  list is put to `users` variable, used as `goal` field in the form and saved to goal/task (are these the same?) `target_name` attribute - what the hell is going on?

Comment: I have renamed the variables appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing

```
task.target_name = int(request.POST.get('goal'))
task.user_name = request.user.scrummyuser.id
```

to

```
task.target_name_id = int(request.POST.get('goal'))
task.user_name_id = request.user.scrummyuser.id
```

or

```
task.target_name = GoalStatus.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('goal'), )
task.user_name = request.user.scrummyuser
```

And I recommend to rename both FK fields: remove `_name` postfix. These are not "names" - these are links to other model instances. So the first one points to `target` via `target_id` value, second one points to `user` via `user_id` value and should be named accordingly.